# VMWare Player: How to set up IP of VM with Network Adapter set to NAT

Tags: linux, networking, vmware, bridge

I set my Network Adapter to the NAT setting, and ran an ifconfig for my machine. 
All the I got back was eth0 and lo. eth0 has the static IP configured I configured back in the days where I was running my VM Bridged with DHCP. Do I need to reconfigure my eth0 settings now and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out your static network settings and change the `bootproto` to DHCP, then reset the network and routing services.

Depends on your distribution, e.g.:

`service network restart`

`/etc/init.d/networking restart` (deprecated)

`/etc/rc.d/routing restart`  -- restart routing services, specific to BSD I believe.

Or simply reboot.

Comment: cool, will that IP be static? If not is there a way to make it so?